# On new Drupal 8 site, sub menu link does not appear?

Tags: drupal, drupal-theming

On new Drupal 8 site, sub menu link does not appear when Basic Page is linked under upper level menu item. Parent link is set to Show as expanded.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Are you trying to add it to the main menu? If so, it will not work. The main menu has no visible sub menu.

Go into the menu, move your link to the same level as 'home' and it will appear next to this link on the upper edge of the page

Answer (score 10):

Answer from @Christophe Galli incorrect.

By default main menu has 1 level that is the reason why you don't see your sub-links. To resolve this - Go to **Block Layout** page, find **Main Navigation** block -> **Configure** it and add more levels for menu.

Comment: Ugh, I wish I knew why Drupal made decisions like this sometimes, since I wasted so much time wondering what I was doing wrong. Thank you for the answer though.